# How to list data from join table in one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

There 3 entities: 1) Question, 2) Tag and join table between them - question_has_tag.

When I make a select query like:

```
select * from question_has_tag as qht where qht.question_id = 6;
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
question_id| tag_id
6          | 1
6          | 2
6          | 3
```

and I needed to get:

```
question_id| tag_id
6          | 1, 2, 3
```

How to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to GROUP them and use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Like

```
SELECT question_id,GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORDER BY tag_id )
FROM question_has_tag as qht 
WHERE qht.question_id = 6
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `group_concat()` function. This function aggregates a particular field, separating them with a arbitrary character(s).

```sql
select
  question_id
  , group_concat(
    distinct tag_id
    order by tag_id
    separator ','
  ) as tag_id
from
  question_has_tags
where
  question_id = 6;
```